# PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR: type "daterange" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my rails migration .

```
create_table :availability_periods do |t|
      t.daterange :date_range
      t.references :availability
end
```

I am getting the above error ! help me , i tried in both mysql , pg same error

Comment: are you sure there is a data type daterange ?

Comment: i am not sure , but i am working on one old application , i found this one

Comment: it's seems like it's not supported any more .https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1734

Comment: I solved this issue by upgrading postgresql 9.1  to 9.2 or above. thanks @SabyasachiGhosh